# Python while loop/range

Tags: python

I need to ask a number from the user and have then if it is in the range of the low/high number then it returns the number and if it isnt in the range, it loops until the number entered is in the range.  I don't really know how exactly to do this but I think I have part of it right.  My main concern is the line "while question != low <= question <= high:"  I feel as if there is a problem with that line.

```
def ask_number(question, low, high):
    question = int(raw_input("Enter a number within the range: "))
    question = ""
    while question != low <= question <= high:
        question = int(raw_input("Enter a number within the range: "))
```

Comment: I'm trying to create this game but I got my answer thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the easiest solution is to use `True` as the condition in the `while` loop, and an `if` inside the loop to break out if the number is fine:

```
def ask_number(low, high):
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(raw_input("Enter a number within the range: "))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if low <= number <= high:
            return number
```

I also added a `try`/`except` statement to prevent the program from crashing if the user enters a string that can't be converted to a number.

Comment: If he wants to accept only integers (and not even accept (by truncating) floats then he could just do something like `if number.isnumeric(): return int(number)`

Comment: @TylerCrompton: You probably mean `number.isdigit()`, since `isnumeric()` does not exist.  This would even rule out leading or trailing whitespace, so it's probably a bit too strict.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop syntax would be more clear if you thought of it this way:  "I want to keep asking the user for the answer *while their answer is less than low or greater than high*."  Translated directly to Python, this would be

```
while question < low or question > high:
```

You should also not assign `""` to `question` as this overwrites the user's first answer.  If they get the number in the range the first time, they will still be asked again.  Basically, you should remove this line:

```
question = ""
```

Your final code should look something like this:

```
def ask_number(low, high):
    assert low < high
    question = int(raw_input("Enter a number within the range: "))
    while question < low or question > high:
        question = int(raw_input("Enter a number within the range: "))
    return question

print(ask_number(5,20))
```

Comment: FYI, this code calls `ask_number()` with three arguments, but it only accepts two.

Comment: @AustinMarshall Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ask_number(low, high):  
    while True:
        number = int(raw_input('Enter a number within the range: '))
        if number in xrange(low, high + 1):
            return number
```

Comment: This is a bad idea.  The Python 2.x `xrange()` object doesn't special-case the `in` operator, so this will loop over the range.  Try `100000000 in xrange(200000000)` to see what I mean. :)  Also note that this works efficiently for Python 3.x `range()` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ask_number(low, high):

    """question cannot be less than the minimum value so we set it below the
    minimum value so that the loop will execute at least once."""

    question = low - 1

    """You want question to be within the range [high, low] (note the
    inclusivity), which would mathematically look like 'low <= question <= high'.
    Break that up into what appears to be one comparison at a time:
    'low <= question and question <= high'. We want the while loop to loop when
    this is false. While loops loop if the given condition is true. So we need to
    negate that expression. Using the DeMorgan's Theorem, we now have
    'low < question or question > high'."""

    while question < low or question > high:

        """And this will obviously update the value for question. I spruced up
        the only argument to raw_input() to make things a bit 'smoother'."""

        question = int(raw_input("Enter a number within the range [%d, %d]: " % _
                   (low, high)))

    # Return question.
    return question
```

Comment: His use of `question = ""` worked fine (on Python 2) as it will never be in the range `low <= question <= high`. "mathematically look like 'low <= question <= high'" Also _Pythonically_ look like that; chained comparisons like that work fine.

Comment: But you can't chain the negation of that (unless you want to do `not (<expression>)`. And yes, I understand that using `""` is fine.